# Model not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

In the context of the MVVM pattern, how would one structure the ViewModel when Models do not implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

I like to keep my Models as simple as possibile and implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface only for binding purposes seems like unwanted complexity. That's why most of the times i require my VMs to wrap model properties like in the following example:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Model model;

    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return model.MyProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (value != model.MyProperty)
            {
                model.MyProperty = value;

                // Trigger the PropertyChanged event
                OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
            }
        }
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

This will make bindings work ok, including two-way ones.

Now, what would happen if a command executes a model method with complex logic (affecting the value of many properties of different objects)? The model is not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged so there's no way we can know it was updated. The only solution that comes to my mind is to use messaging (mediator pattern) to inform all VMs of the execution of the method so that each VM fires the PropertyChanged event for each potentially affected property:

```
// Sample ICommand.Execute() implementation
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    var model = (Model)parameter;

    model.VeryComplexMethod();

    // Just an example, the string "VeryComplexMethodExecuted" is
    // sent to all listening VMs. Those VMs will in turn fire the
    // PropertyChanged event for each property that may have changed
    // due to the execution of the complex model method.
    Messaging.Broadcast("VeryComplexMethodExecuted");
}
```

Please share your ideas, thanks.

Comment: *what would happen if a command executes a model method with complex logic*... business models generally *don't* have functionality built in. In WPF, that functionality goes in the main view models that are data bound to the views (not the view models that wrap the business models).

Comment: If you're model class has a method, you could argue that it has reached a level of complexity already - adding INotifyPropertyChanged is not that much more. It is certainly less complex than the alternates which as I see it are - notify all your properties or specify in your command which properties will have updated (this creates a dependency between classes way more complex than implementing the interface)

Comment: @Sheridan Do you mean Models are data-only? And where do you put the logic? In the command itself (or in a VM method, it's the same)? What if the App is a chess game? Isn't AI part of the model?

Comment: *In WPF, that functionality goes in the main view models that are data bound to the views (not the view models that wrap the business models).*

Comment: In a game scenario, personally, I would have the AI in an injected provider and keep the model POCO (I would still implement INotify)

Comment: @Sheridan please explain the difference between "main VM" and "VM that wraps a model"

Comment: @kidshaw even if i have my AI injected the problem remains. AI execution would change model properties directly without VMs knowing it.

Comment: Typically, when using MVVM, we declare one view model per view, in order to provide all of the relevant data and functionality. However, when we wrap a business model and implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, there is not necessarily any related view. I therefore tend to think of these as pure `DataType` classes rather than view models for this reason, but I know that some people still call them view models. So when I refer to a view model, it is the kind that is supposed to be used with a single view.

Comment: Generally speaking: i see my models as data and business logic. My VMs are there to expose models in a way that makes sense to the views (xaml). VMs will also provide commands so that an input-event on the view can trigger some logic (of any kind).

Comment: Yes your AI would affect your model, which is why - if you bind to it, it needs to notify. I would view this as a nested VM.

Comment: @Sheridan so chess AI goes inside a VM? I don't feel like that's a VM responsibility.

Comment: @kidshaw so you agree that AI is VM?

Comment: I do not like the Model knowing someone will bind to it

Comment: No, I wouldn't say that. For something as complex as Chess AI, I'd put that into a separate, service class that the view models have access to via a base view model property. It would still be accessible from the view model, but it would be separate to enable testing to be performed on it.

Comment: @Sheridan so chess AI is not VM but VM can access it. I agree with that. Infact i consider AI to be Model. Model is what my App is about. It's about chess. AI is part of it!

Comment: Not really - I would inject the AI into the ViewModel and interact with it to get updated values, which I would make available in the VM.

Comment: I mean my models should be 100% autonomous. I should be able to create a Console App chess game reusing the same Model without having to bring in the VMs. So AI is part of the Model.

Comment: @kidshaw i do understand injecting the AI into the VM but that's not the point. Your solution still requires Models to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Maybe it's the way to go but i'd like to hear about existing alternatives.

Comment: *So AI is part of the Model*... you've totally missed the point, but you just do it your way. There's no point in you using MVVM if you don't understand it. I suggest that you read some more tutorials to get a better understanding. Either way, this has gone on for long enough now, so I'm out of this conversation.

Comment: Seems like a bit of semantics - Your VM should represent the needs of your view, so your AI can be AiModel but rather than it maintaining its own properties, make it return values which you can handle in your VM.

Comment: @Sheridan please could you only explain me what - in your opinion - i'm not understanding about MVVM?

Comment: I never heard business logic should go into VMs. Probably that's what i'm missing.

Comment: **Last comment:** It's not about business logic going into view models, it's about no logic going into models. Each view model should supply *everything* that a view requires, be that data, or functionality. But that doesn't mean that the functionality has to be built into the view model. It just depends on the situation as to what gets declared where. MVVM provides *separation of concerns* (look it up if you don't know what it is), but if you put functionality into your model, you break that. But then that might be fine for a small program. There is no single correct answer.

Comment: @Sheridan i still don't get your point. To me logic that changes the Model (in potentially "complex" ways) is part of it. VMs will execute that logic in commands when needed. I think we just disagree on that point but i don't see why my ideas contrast the MVVM pattern.

Comment: @sheridan the concept of 'no logic goes into models' is definitely not MVVM. 'no display logic' yes, but not 'no logic'. Models won't always be just data. In this particular case I'd be looking at how my model signals that it is 'ready', assuming that some operations take time (calculating a move, for example). This message won't be tied to UI implementation, but should be something the VM needs to worry about, so that it can then ensure its knowledge of the model is accurate and up to date.

Comment: @Mashton i do agree. ViewModel contains display logic and interacts with model. It should not contain business rules (imho)

Comment: @dan That's right, otherwise you have to recreate your business rules every time you try to change the display technology

Comment: If the `ViewModel` class contains a reference to `Model` and implementation of the `Execute()` method of the command, then what is the point of passing the instance of `Model` as the command parameter?

Comment: @SergeyBrunov does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

Declare your members virtual and use something like Castle Dynamic Proxy to inject change notification automatically:

http://ayende.com/blog/4106/nhibernate-inotifypropertychanged

This has to be used with care when your models are being created in your data layer because it returns a new instance entirely. Your database code will think the object has changed and serialize it back out again which will in turn have a huge impact on performance. Fortunately all the good ORMs provide mechanisms for you to substitute in class wrappers at creation time.